# How to use char in scanf by using loop?

Tags: c, char, scanf, billing

I want to make simple billing software but I don't know to fix this problem

```c
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main()
{
    char a[20];
    int i, j, b;
    i = 0;
    printf("How many item you have?\n>>> ");
    scanf("%d", &j);
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        
        printf("Type the name of item no. %d?\n>>> ", i + 1);
        scanf("%c", &a);
        printf("Type the item quantity?\n>>> ");
        scanf("%d", &b);
    }
        
    return 0;
}
```

This code is only for asking questions, as you can see. In this code everything is fine but, when I run this code, the output is:

```
How many item you have?
>>> 4
Type the name of item no. 1?
>>> Type the item quantity?
>>>
```

Everything seems fine but I haven't entered the item name and the loop is asking the 2nd question directly. How is it even possible?

Comment: When you press the `Enter` key for the item count (the input for `j`), then that is added in the input buffer as a newline. This newline is then read by the next `scanf` call for the input to `a`. This is a very common beginners problem and if you search a little you should easily find out how to solve it.

Comment: `scanf("%c", &a);` This will only read 1 `char`, not a name. Use `%19s` instead. And of course, never ever use `scanf` without checking the return value.

Comment: Reading the source a little more, it seems that what you want to read into `a` is a ***string***, not a single character. Again it's something which you should have been able to find out yourself very easily, as any decent book or tutorial or class should have told you how to use `scanf` to read strings.

Comment: On another but unrelated note, please don't use simple single-letter names for your variables. Use something that describes its use, like for example `name` instead of `a`. That will make it *much* easier to read and understand your code.

Answer (score 1):

The `%c` format specifier for `scanf` reads a *single* character. To read a string (array) of characters, use the `%s` format specifier. Also, for such arrays, you don't need the `&` (address of) operator, as the array name itself will 'decay' to a pointer to its first element:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a[20];
    int i, j, b;
    i = 0;
    printf("How many item you have?\n>>> ");
    scanf("%d", &j);
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        printf("Type the name of item no. %d?\n>>> ", i + 1);
        scanf("%19s", a); // The "19" limits input size and allows space for the nul-terminator
        printf("Type the item quantity?\n>>> ");
        scanf("%d", &b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```